# Enterprise Scan: Error archiving documents

Tags: enterprise, dms, opentext, livelink

I'm using Enterprise Scan software for managing my documents on my local business, but when I try to archive documents into server, I get those error messages:

> “critical error during archiving content server API function call failed error adding version to subscribe numbers the archiving procedure will be aborted
>
> “critical error during archiving unable to write data to transport connection an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host the archiving procedure will be aborted”

How could suggest me any solution or who could tell me what is the problem?

This is an error we get when we try to archive(upload) documents:
[image]

Comment: Is there something in the log file? Have a look here: %userprofile%\AppData\Local\OpenText\Enterprise Scan\Log\IXClient.log. You can set the log level to Extended from Enterprise Scan menu (Tools -> user options)

Answer (score 0):

1. close the enterprise scan
2. go to c:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\OpenText\Enterprise Scan\StorageV1
3. delete high size file = (imagestream1)
   open enterprise scan and use.

have a good day